# Verb to use with "workload"

Tags: word-choice, verbs, word-usage

Just wondering which verb is the most natural to native speakers to use with 'workload.'

Among

> I wish to **receive** heavier workload.
>   I wish to **take** heavier workload.
>   I wish to **have** heavier workload.

which would be appropriate?

Comment: Do we *need* a verb even? "I wish for a heavier workload" could do? (This is of course, not an answer, and the question is an eminently valid one.)

Comment: I suppose *be assigned* would work: "I wish to be assigned a heavier workload."

Comment: So I guess workload is not something one can voluntarily wish for but rather something to be given to.

Comment: "I {want / would like} a heavier workload" is how I think most native speakers would word this peculiar desire. *Work* is the activity that people know they must perform in order to be able to earn money; *workload* is the term usually used to describe the burden, volume or pressure of the work they are expected to perform.

Comment: *Wish* is voluntary, naturally, and no one can tell you to wish or not to wish for anything. :) However, workload is assigned and one can wish for a higher workload.

Comment: See also: "VERB + WORKLOAD have" on the Online OXFORD Collocation Dictionary at http://oxforddictionary.so8848.com/search?word=workload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Native speakers would most likely use the verb "**take on**" for a noun like workload, as it is viewed as a type of obligation or chore (as one would "take on" a debt or a dependent).  Note that native speakers would also use the indefinite article in your sentence, as a workload is a measurable single thing.  So, they would say:

> I wish to take on a heavier workload.

Of course, most people would rarely want to express that sentiment, regardless of language.

Comment: It's just sometimes we have nothing to do at work while waiting for other teams to complete their tasks. Gets boring after a few days.

Comment: I was half-joking there on the end, but forgot my smiley face. :-)  Given your context, however, I might suggest expressing your desire with a different noun.  **Workload** in this context implies something more ongoing, as if you wish to be given extra work all the time.  If you are really just saying you'd like some extra work *now*, but are satisfied with your workload in general, I'd use a noun like "tasks", as in "I wish to take on some more tasks".  That doesn't imply anything about the future, where "workload" implies that you want more work regularly.

Answer (score 1):

***I would welcome a heavier workload*** seems, idiomatically, to express what you are wanting to say.

Answer (score 1):

I would say

I wish to be given a heavier workload.

Or

I wish I could have a heavier workload.

"Take on" suggests too strongly (to me) that the extra workload will be pushing me to my limits.  Which may not be the case.